# Leapfrog Crammer won't mount as a USB flash drive

Tags: 11.10, usb, usb-modeswitch

I can't seem to get the [Leapfrog Crammer](http://www.leapfrog.com/gaming/crammer/how.html) study and sound system to show up as a flash drive under ubuntu so I can transfer stuff to it.

I don't want to install the leapfrog bloatware, can someone help me with this?

Additional Information:

- When I plug my crammer into my computer it shows a 1 MB file system with a link to download the crammer software. I want to know how to access the rest of the crammer's file system so I can transfer music to it.
- The crammer does not show any other partitions in natulius. According to an article on the internet, the crammed is divided into three partitions: One with a link to install the crammer software, one with all content(music, flash cards, etc.) and one for firmware. I want to know how to access the one with the content so I can add music to the player. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.leapfrog.com/gaming/crammer/how.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before trying anything too complicated, have you opened Disk Utility and looked to see if the other partitions are listed and just not mounted?

We've seen an increase recently in "flip flop" USB hardware. This hardware (typically things like USB 3G modems or printers) originally registers itself to the host computer as a USB mass storage device (flash drive) containing the driver, and then the driver is able to change the mode of the hardware to access its real functions. I suspect that this may be what is happening with the Leapfrog Crammer.

The piece of software responsible for automatically changing the mode of this hardware in Ubuntu is called [`usb_modeswitch`](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/). In all likelihood, `usb_modeswitch` doesn't yet know that it needs to change the mode of the Leapfrog Crammer, and may not know how. The `usb_modeswitch` homepage has documentation on [how to modify the configuration to handle new devices](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#contrib)

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out and detailed answer. I will try your disk utility suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: The other partitions don't appear in disk utility. Can you provide simple instructions on how to use usb-modeswitch to switch the active partitions? I have adequate ubuntu knowledge but I'm not smart enough to figure out the very technical instructions on the man pages and on the link you suggested.

Comment: did you get to make it works ? I m having same issue with my Leapfrog TAG and I m also not smart enough too be able to create a configuration for usb_modeswitch. I also doubt that usb_modeswitch can be the answer because all examples are to swish from flash drive to modem where our concern is to keep our Leapfrog device as a flash drive.