# How can I mount my LeapFrog Tag USB device?

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

I have no problem with my USB key devices: there are mounted automatically.
But for the **LeapFrog Tag USB device** it is not mounted automatically.

[image]

So I look in the [Ubuntu documentation to mount USB manually.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Manually_Mounting)

But `fdisk` returns only info about my hard disk, nothing about LeapFrog USB.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Périphérique Amorce  Début        Fin      Blocs     Id  Système<br>
/dev/sda1   *        2048   606713855   303355904   83  Linux<br>
/dev/sda2       606715902   625141759     9212929    5  Étendue<br>
/dev/sda5       606715904   625141759     9212928   82  partition d'échange Linux / Solaris
```

I found some commands able to list this USB device:
 - **lsusb**
 - **udevadm** (need unplug the device before using the command and then plug it to see it)

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0f63:0700 **LeapFrog** Enterprises POGO<br>
```

and

```
$ udevadm monitor --udev
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
UDEV  [1915.787445] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2 (usb)
UDEV  [1915.796226] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0 (usb)
```

So I hope to be able to mount it with something like:
`sudo mount -t ??? /dev/sdb??? /media/leapfrog`

**How can I know which option and what is the path of the device?**
**Is there a way to use USB ID from `lsusb` ?**

Comment: Is your device the same as what is described in this wiki page? maybe the unlocking stuff there could help? http://elinux.org/Didj_USB_Mounting

Comment: I would say no, but after search on google, my Tag and this Didj seems to be products from LeapFrog company. So I'll see if unlocking can help - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I give up:

the only way I found to make this Leapfrog Tag working is to plug it on a Windows XP PC.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way

```
sudo -i
blkid
```

then plugin ur usb then run

```
blkid
```

---

## before Usb

[image]

## After Usb Plugged-in

[image]

## so now i know my usb is vfat & its sdb1

if its auto mounted and u want to mount it manually 
  1st run `umount /dev/sdb1`

now manually mounting

```
mkdir /media/myusb
```

or make a folder where u want to mount your usb

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/myusb
```

now usb has been mounted on /media/myusb

also check these links

http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#contrib

[Leapfrog Crammer won't mount as a USB flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75946/leapfrog-crammer-wont-mount-as-a-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: unfortunately command blkid does not list anything new, only command lsusb does, so I can not still get any /dev/s???

Comment: have you checked the 2 linked at the end

Comment: what I understand from your 2 links is that the problem is not that the device is locked but in fact this device acts 1st as a flash storage and then 2nd should switch to USB device but 2nd step is not happening - right ?

Comment: well truly speaking i dont know about it & that is why i have pasted the link below ...

Comment: Disk Utility which one

Comment: I ve used the default disk utility on Oneiric, it lists my hard disk + 16 SSD disks: from /dev/nbd0 to /dev/nbd15. Trying with  GPARTED I see only my hard disk.

Comment: I m not smart enough to create a configuration for usb_modeswitch and I doubt that I need to switch from a flash device to an other kind of device because my main goal is to use it as a flash device

Answer (score 1):

## This is not a real answer

I just want to record the tasks I'm using to try to solve my problem based on the [wiki about Didj](http://elinux.org/Didj_USB_Mounting) given by [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom):

#### I'm trying to unlock access to the LeapFrog Tag USB:

1- install [sg3_util](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/sg3_utils.8.html)
2- get "some" Leapfrog Didj programs (Didj seems to be an other Leapfrog USB device)

```
$ wget http://medialib.leapfrog.com/didj_opensource_code/Didj-Linux-4222-20090422-1236.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf Didj-Linux-4222-20090422-1236.tar.gz
```

3- searh the programm scsi_custom.c

```
$ find . -name scsi_custom.c
./Didj-Linux-4222-20090422-1236/host_tools/scsi/scsi_custom.c
```

4a- perhaps program needs to be customized for the Leapfrog TAG instead of the Didj device ? but I don't know what part to be modified.

4b- compile the program scsi_custom.c (**with some warning unfortunately**)

```
$ cd Didj-Linux-4222-20090422-1236/host_tools/scsi
$ gcc -o scsi_custom scsi_custom.c
scsi_custom.c: In function ‘print_reply’:
scsi_custom.c:201:3: attention : format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
```

5- plug the LeapFrog Tag USB and turn it on
to cross-check that the device is well plugged, I do `lsusb` and get something like:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 0f63:0700 LeapFrog Enterprises POGO
```

6- and here, according to [the wiki](http://elinux.org/Didj_USB_Mounting#Under_Linux), I should `$tail -f /var/log/messages`
    but /var/log/messages does not exist.
    Else trying:
- `$ tail -f /var/log/dmesg` does not return much
- `$ dmesg | grep -i usb` returns this
    `[20221.960029] usb 5-1: new full speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd`

-`$ dmesg | grep -i scsi` returns :

```
[    1.228576] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    1.252491] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA Hitachi HDT72101 ST6O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.252724] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    1.263917] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.331646] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Note that /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are hard disk, not the USB device that I m looking for.

**So I m still unable to know the /dev/sg? for my device**.
So I m unable to continue this solution.

Comment: ... try `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` instead - n.b. you dont need sudo in-front of the command.

Comment: I ve update the answer with `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` (in step 6) but it won't help I guess. Perhaps the warnings (in step 4) when compiling the scsi program are the source of the issue ?

Comment: those warnings are pretty standard fair... I doubt they are significant... in the DidJ code, are their any usb_ids in the header (.h) or code files (.c)?  may be you need to add your usb_id in the code?

Comment: In case anyone else is still looking at this in 2014... In Ubuntu distributions, /var/log/messages can be found at /var/log/syslog I hope that helps somebody. If anyone has some info on the LeapFrog Leap Reader, I am trying to get our grand-daughter's one working in 'buntu wish me luck!

Comment: @Martin thank you to keep us inform if you find a solution