# How do I list all storage devices (thumb drives/external hard drives) that are connected via USB, from the command line?

Tags: command-line, usb

I would like to list ONLY devices connected via usb.

The problem is that Ubuntu seems to see all thumb drives as removable (in `/sys/block/*/removable`), but it does not see external hard drives the same way.

This is a bit more specific than [How to detect an USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166420/how-to-detect-an-usb-device)

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking for the mounted disks, a simple

```
df
```

will list them along with all your other disks along with some useful info.

Comment: but this gives all block devices, not just those attached via USB.

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend checking the udev properties of the devices, specifically the `ID_BUS` property:

```
for device in /sys/block/*
do
    if udevadm info --query=property --path=$device | grep -q ^ID_BUS=usb
    then
        echo $device
    fi
done
```

Comment: This spits out devices for my built in card reader as well even when there are not cards inserted.

Comment: @b_laoshi: yep, those will still report as storage devices, but with no media present.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
lsusb
```

will give you what you want, at least if I understand what you're asking.  (Of course, it lists all usb devices, not just storage.)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo lshw -class disk -short
```

Will list all devices and their human-readable names.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

### <strike>Listing only attached *USB storage* devices</strike>

*Edit: When I have some time, I'll revisit this post to make it list only USB devices. For now, it lists all devices mounted in `/media` which may be good enough for some people.*

### Listing all devices mounted in `/media`

All of the other answers here appear to fail in filtering out either non USB storage devices or non-storage USB devices. <strike>Here is a command that should list only storage devices attached via USB.</strike> *One exception, which is likely not to matter to anyone is that this will not display connected USB optical drives with mounted media.*

**Requirements for this to work**

- USB devices must be mounted. Ubuntu desktop OSs typically auto-mount by default
- Media must be mounted in the `/media` directory. If your USB device is configured in fstab to mount somewhere else, you'd have to tweak the following commands

**Listing USB storage devices**
In my particular case for a script I'm writing, I list individual partitions. Here are two commands. One will list partitions of attached devices, and the other will simply list devices.

- Listing partitions:
  `lsblk | grep /media | grep -oP "sd[a-z][0-9]?" | awk '{print "/dev/"$1}'`
  Sample Output:

  ```
  /dev/sdd1
  /dev/sdi1
  /dev/sdj1
  /dev/sdj2
  ```
- Listing devices:
  `lsblk | grep /media | grep -oP "sd[a-z]" | awk '{print "/dev/"$1}' | sort | uniq`
  Sample Output:

  ```
  /dev/sdd
  /dev/sdi
  /dev/sdj
  ```

Comment: What about partitions of internal disks that go mounted in `/media`?

Comment: That would present a problem, but one that's not likely to affect most users. I'll give it some thought and update later.

Answer (score 1):

[`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/lsblk.8.html) can show you the connection type, and makes it easy to configure the output you want.

Use `lsblk -O` to see it's full output, or check `lsblk --help` to see the available output columns. Then use `-o` (or `--output`) to list the columns you want.

For example:

```
lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,FSTYPE,RM,TRAN,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
```

This uses

- `TRAN` : the "device transport type". Usually "usb" or "sata".
- `RM` : "removable device".
- `SIZE` : to be able to exclude empty USB slots. These may show up but with a size of 0.

To use it in a script, there is the `-P` option : "use key='value' output format".

So for example:

```bsh
lsblk -P -b -o 'KNAME,TYPE,TRAN,RM,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT' \
| while read -r vars; do
    eval "$vars"
    if ((SIZE)) && [ "$TRAN" = "usb" ]; then
       echo "$KNAME is a USB disk: $vars"
    fi
done
```