# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell XPC 8700 no longer see compact flash drive(s)

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell XPC 8700 Desktop. Sometime in the past the past 6 weeks or so my desktop no longer recognizes my compact flash drive(s).  When I insert a SD card nothing happens anymore.  I've looked at the "Disks" application and the icons for the various usb CF drives are there but nothing appears to happen when I insert or remove a card.

I've tried manually mounting `/dev/sdd` (per information from Disks) but I only get an error message:

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdd
```

(the card is inserted fully). I've also tried `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sde` and `/dev/sdf` on the off chance that something isn't configured right but the same error message appears.

When I enter `sudo fdisk -l` from the command line I get information about my hard drives `/dev/sda` `/dev/sdb`; `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` and `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1` 
even though I have an SD card inserted.  I assume that something has happened as a result of the recent updates over the past few weeks but now I have no clue how to fix this problem.

I assume that the problem started with one or more of the updates I've installed over the past 4-6 weeks (maybe more) since I've made no other changes to my system. Does anybody have any suggestions????  I desperately need to get this fixed ASAP!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the hardware itself is not an issue;

Run

```
$ dmesg -T | tail
```

*The -T option prints human readable timestamps.*

Insert the device and run

```
$ dmesg -T | tail
```

again and see if anything has changed in the output. If your computer sees the new device, you will find a note of it here. This will include a /dev/sd? you can use to try and manually mount it somewhere, but be warned

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdd /mnt
```

is an attempt to mount the raw disk as opposed to, say, the first partition like:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt
```

If this still doesn't help, here are some more powerful tools to investigate.
[How to detect an USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166420/how-to-detect-an-usb-device)