# Detecting if any device is being plugged in

Tags: scripts, peripherals

Hi I wanted to write a script that ran whenever any device was plugged in. If found [How to detect an USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166420/how-to-detect-an-usb-device) for usb ports. And [How can I run a script when the power supply is plugged-in or -out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590727/how-can-i-run-a-script-when-the-power-supply-is-plugged-in-or-out) for powersupply, for powersupply however only featured if it was plugged in and then contounsly preformed an action. I need a script to run once whenever something is plugged in. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect your devices. There's a system, called `udev` that notices when device events happen. Read `man udev`, and `man -k udev`.

Comment: @waltinator thx! If you where to write an answer with an example script, I will approve and upvote. If not thx for the usefull tip!

Comment: Sorry, writing `udev` rules (not scripts) for a remote system, with unknown hardware, is not something that's easy. I won't. It's up to you to learn about `udev`, look at `udev` on your system, search for `udev` tutorials on the web, ... Don't fall victim to UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool).

Comment: Yeah thx, true that. It is easy to falling in to thinking learning something is just a trivial step in accomplishing your goal. I will have a look at it when I have the time, but in retrospective do not need to check all the inputs, yielding this question rather useless. But thx some great dev wisdom I all to often forget :)!